# Spring JSR 303 Validation access other field value while Edit/Add

Tags: java, validation, spring-mvc

I have a requirement wherein I want to use a Bean for both update/add. Now i have a validation as in the name should be unique.

Now during add the validation part is working correctly as it is checking for unique value by querying DB.

Now when i wanted to update the same record, it is trying to check the unique constraint in the DB and fails as the record already exists.

**Role Bean**

```
public class Role {
    @NotEmpty
    @Pattern(regexp = "[a-zA-Z ]*")
    @UniqueValue(query = AppConstants.UNIQUE_VALIDATION_DB_QUERY)
    private String roleName;
    private String roleDesc;
    private boolean active;
 private String maskRoleName;

    public String getRoleName() {
        return roleName;
    }

    public void setRoleName(String roleName) {
        this.roleName = roleName;
    }

    public String getRoleDesc() {
        return roleDesc;
    }

    public void setRoleDesc(String roleDesc) {
        this.roleDesc = roleDesc;
    }

    public boolean isActive() {
        return active;
    }

    public void setActive(boolean active) {
        this.active = active;
    }
}
```

**My Custom Annotation Validator**

```
public class UniqueValueValidator implements ConstraintValidator<UniqueValue, String> {

    @Autowired
    private ValidationDAO validationDAO;

    private String query;

    public void initialize(UniqueValue uniqueValue) {
        this.query = uniqueValue.query();
    }

    public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
            if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(value) && !StringUtils.isEmpty(query)) {
                return validationDAO.isValidUniqueField(query, value);
            }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Now when I update only the RoleDesc Field from screen the role name is validated and throws the validation error as the same role name exists in DB. Is there a way wherein I can send other variable to my custom validator from screen saying the following is update screen so only validate the field if it is changed from its previous value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came with a work around by annotating on a getter method where all the required fields are returned as a single map through that method and in the validationIMPL I retrieved all the required information and processed accordingly.

```
 private String roleName;

 @UniqueValue(query = AppConstants.UNIQUE_VALIDATION_DB_QUERY)
 public Map<String,String> getUniqueValidator(){
   Map<String,String> validatorMap=new HashMap<String,String>();

   validatorMap.put("ACTION",type of action(update/new)):
   validatorMap.put("VALUE",this.roleName):
   return validatorMap;
 }

 public String getRoleName() {
        return roleName;
 }

 public void setRoleName(String roleName) {
        this.roleName = roleName;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are probably looking for are [Groups](http://beanvalidation.org/1.1/spec/#validationapi-validatorapi-groups). You would modify your annotation to:

```
@UniqueValue(query = AppConstants.UNIQUE_VALIDATION_DB_QUERY, groups = {CreationGroup.class})
```

You'll also need to create a `CreationGroup` interface.

Then you will need to update your interceptor that calls the bean validation to use contextual information (possibly provided by another annotation wrapping the method where the validation is happening) to be something like this:

```
if (myMethodIsCreatingANewRecord()) {
    validator.validate(address, Default.class, CreationGroup.class);
} else {
    validator.validate(address, Default.class);
}
```

Comment: But how do I pass the info of validate only if value is changed. As I need to validate even in add/edit... but in case of edit I should validate only if value is changed

Comment: Is there a way to pass other field value(maskRoleName) along with current field... so that I can check if masroleName=roleName then no validation

Comment: Presumably you have a primary key you can use to look up the entity when you are updating to check if the name has changed. That's the info you'd want to pass along with your Role object. For this particular problem, however, I'd probably add a unique constraint to the database column instead and just let it cause failures whenever it is violated.

Comment: Thanks for your reply chill. I don't want to go till dao layer and throw the exception. Instead I would like to handle that at validation layer. Is it not possible to handle such type of scenarios? If we could access other variables in my unique validator I think we can pass the info on how to validate it. But I do not know whether it is possible to do in that way??

Comment: Well, as I mentioned in the answer, you should have enough information from where you are calling the validator to get the old version of the entity and use that to determine if the field changed. Like, if your service is calling a method like `editRole(roleId, roleBean)`, when you intercept that, just grab the roleId parameter and use it to load up the existing entity to use for comparison.

Comment: I call the validation with @Valid Annotation in parameter itself. Even though i call with validator object how do i get the field value in it... for example consider i have validator.validate(address, Default.class, UpdationGroup.class); how do i send old RoleName which is entered previously and avoid unique validation only for roleName and go ahead with other validations like not null and pattern.

Comment: Is it not possible to send other field values for validation :(